# LDAP Authentication on Windows

Tags: php, apache, authentication, ldap

i have an 64 bit Windows Platform and Postgresql 8.4 installed(as Apache, EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP is installed on Pstgres).. I need to authenticate to system using Active Directory(or LDAP?) credentials but even tough i enabled LDAP and restarted Apache on **error** log i see  **PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ldap_connect() in *path/to/my/phpfile***.. PHP script i use is below,

```
<?php

$user = $_POST["myUserName@mydomain.com"];
$pass = $_POST["muPassword"];
//in our system, we already use this account for LDAP authentication on the server above
$ldap_serv = 'ldap://192.168.69.10';
$ldap_port = '389';
$lc = ldap_connect($ldap_serv, $ldap_port);
ldap_set_option($lc, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($lc, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($lc,$user,$pass);
if ($ldapbind == false) {
  echo 'username or password is wrong';
}
else
{
echo "You Logged in";
echo "<br><br><br>Wellcome<br><br><br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PHP LDAP extension is required to use LDAP functions. Just check it's uncommented in your php.ini (`extension=php_ldap.dll`)

Comment: I uninstalled postgres and installed WAMP, uncommented that line and it works properly

Comment: when I saw `php.ini` file this `(extension = php_ldap.dll)` was not there I just added this line and ldap enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP extension is clearly not loading. A couple things to try:

- run 'php -m' from the command line and ensure that ldap is in the list of modules, and that there are no errors related to ldap.
- ensure that the apache php module is using the php.ini that you modified ( and look for php.ini on the page)

Comment: @dealby good answer but i couldn't rum 'php -m' from command line. I'm using Postgresql(which lies on a version of Apache). And i'm uncommenting extention from php.ini of Apache inside Postgres

Comment: @ilis This is confusing to me.... Postgres is your database - I'm not sure what you mean by Apache inside of it. Theoretically, apache is using a php module to interpret your scripts and serve up the results. Then there's usually php.exe as well, which allows you to run php scripts from the command line. Do you see ldap support when you run a script that has <? phpinfo(); ?> in it? Anything in the apache logs about the php ldap module not being loaded?

Comment: sorry, i mean Apache is a part of Postgresql, i havent installed any other Apache or PHP modules, i tried phpinfo() but there is almost nothing about ldap, which means it isnt activated.

Comment: In the phpinfo() output, do you see the same php.ini file that you modified? Can you check your apache logs to ensure there were no errors when it was restarted?