# LDAP Authentication via PHP continues to fail

Tags: php, html, forms, ldap

I am trying to authenticate to Active Directory using PHP and LDAP. Unfortunately, when I try to send the username through the form it's failing. Even if I specify the $userName and $passWord within the authenticate function, the function still returns false. What am I doing wrong?

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
function authenticate($userName,$passWord) {

//Active Directory Server
$ldap_host = "example.com";

//Active Directory DN
$ldap_dn = "DC=myCompany,DC=org";

//Connect to AD Server
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host)
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
utf8_decode($passWord);

//Specify Active Directory  
ldap_set_option ($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

//Verify userName and passWord
if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $userName, $passWord)) {
    //if valid
    $ldapResults = 'Bind Successful';
    return true;        
} else {
    //invalid username or password
    return false;
}
};
if(isset($_POST['userName'])) {
//authenticate via function
if(authenticate($_POST['userName'],$_POST['passWord']))
{
    //successfully authenticated (scroll down)
    header("Location: example.com");
    $error = null;
} else {
    //failed authentication
    $error = 1;
}
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm" action="login.php">
            <ul>
                 <li>
                    <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="password" id="passWord" name="passWord" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In"></input>
                </li>
            </ul>
 </form>
```

Comment: You could remove the @ from the start of the `ldap_bind()` call, so you can see if it's generating any errors.

Comment: Are you getting anything from `ldap_errno()`?

Comment: I've changed the bind line to:
`if($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, 'myDomain\\'.$userName, $passWord)) {` but I still get the else statement `$error = 1;` that shoots my Login Failed message. Prior to that, I had to type myDomain\username, without the myDomain\ it would say unable to bind.

Comment: I also added, per your suggestions, `<div class="error"><?php echo(ldap_errno());?></div>` and get a message of: Warning: ldap_errno() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\status\login.php on line 33. 

Line 33 is `else {
  //failed authentication
  $error = 1;
 }`, or if it doesn't add the lines from the include it would be the line of the ldap_errno() itself.

Comment: Your `ldap_errno()` call is wrong; @andrewsi just listed the function for you, not the full syntax. With your code you would use `echo ldap_errno($ldap);`

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be using an ActiveDirectory for authentication against, you might use `userName@myDomain` as username instead of `myDomain\\username`. Found that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394394/ldap-authentication-on-windows?rq=1).

You should also be able to provide the full DN to the `ldap_bind` function.

So you either have to type that into the `userName` field or you use a second bind with a known (or anonymous) user to fetch the DN for a given username to use that for the final bind.

I just hacked together an [example gist](https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592) to illustrate that. In line 13 you have the first bind to retrieve the DN of the user and in line 70 you have the final bind using the retrieved `DN` and the provided password to check the credentials. Everything in between is simple checking for errors.