# Ldap Connection on Web Server

Tags: php, linux, apache, ldap

I have very limited knowledge on LDAP and its configuration, and I have been trying to figure out one issue that takes place when I am running the program that is written in php, but so far it's unsuccessful.

The server, I am working on is a ldap server, which is running on Apache. After testing the program locally (ldap://localhost:10389/) the same was hosted on the web server (Linux Apache server). while running the same program via

> http : / / abc.net:2020 /conn.php

it stopped at the `"$ldapconn = ldap_connect($host, $port)"` and moving to next, and at the same time not providing any error message, therefore, I am unable to find out where the issue is actually taking place.

The program I wrote on php is :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        $host = "ldap://1.1.11.111";
        $port = "389";

        echo "<br><br>Connecting to ".$host."..........";
        $ldapconn = ldap_connect($host, $port) 
                  or die("Could not connect to {$ldaphost}");
        echo "<br><font style='color:blue'>Connected Successfully!</font>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

How I can test that the server has all the relevant dlls ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$host = "ldap://1.1.11.111";`  can you try after removing **ldap:** prefix

Comment: Thanks. But still not working. I tried as $host = "1.1.11.111"; and $host = "//1.1.11.111";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are describing it looks like the LDAP-Extension is not installed on the server.

You should be able to find a note on that in the log-files if logging isn't completely disabled.

To be sure whether the server has LDAP installed or not, create a phpinfo-page and look whether there is a section about LDAP in it. The easiest is to create a new file within the docroot of the server and add the following content to it:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

More info can be found at [the documentation](http://php.net/phpinfo)

Should the LDAP-Module not be installed (meaning there is no trace of LDAP in the output of the phpinfo-page) you need to install it. That though highly depends on your setup, but you might want to have a look at [the documentation for installing extensions](http://php.net/manual/fa/install.windows.extensions.php) and ensure that the LDAP-extension actually is loaded by adding the path to it with an `extension`-part of your `php.ini`-file like this:

```
extension=php_ldap.dll
```

Find further informations probably in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394394/ldap-authentication-on-windows)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. As said in the above comment, I have created a file with phpinfo() under docroot. I compared with the local phpinfo() result with hosted output and found that ldap part is missing. i.e. LDAP Support enabled
- Then php5-ldap was installed  but still not get enabled and found (https://gist.github.com/anhtuank7c/52bdefb1ea04060032d8a27ad9d39ede) that php5.6-ldap has to be separately installed (i.e. php5-ldap not cater php5.6)                                                                                              
             Thanks a lot for the advise.